# How do you use a ubuntu flash drive to boot the computer

Tags: boot, system-installation, flash, usb-drive

I have downloaded Ubuntu on a flash drive and followed all of the directions.

Apparently there is a solution for starting Ubuntu on a 32-bit Windows XP system from a flash dive. It seems that all instructions have never encountered the questions that windows XP asks when you go into the BIOS. The people who put up a web site or a tutorial on youtube omit the necessary things to complete the set up.

How does one actually create a USB drive that will boot on Windows explorer?

Answer (score 1):

To boot from a Ubuntu live USB drive:
Insert the flash drive
Start/restart the machine
Go into the BIOS
Change the boot order so that the USB drive is the first boot device.

I faced the same question a few weeks ago. Google and perhaps greater familairity with BIOS settings than you, resolved the problem for me. It's common for older BIOSes not to offer the USB drive as a boot option unless there's a bootable drive inserted into the USB port, and this seems to be quite a common source of confusion.

Your question reveals that you have misunderstood something about how the BIOS works or what it is - Windows XP does not display a message when you go into the BIOS, as Windows XP is not loaded when you enter the BIOS. I can't guess what that misunderstaning might be, but it may be that this is the source of your problem. I'd suggest reading up a bit on what a BIOS is and does.